# does not using InvokerTransformer means my code is safe?

Tags: java, security, serialization, apache-commons

Looking at this issue/vulnerability: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COLLECTIONS-580

can I say that if in my app code, the guilty class **InvokerTransformer** is not used, then my app is not vulnerable to this? Or not necessary ?

Comment: If you look into your static source code and see no InvokerTransformer calls being made, it still is not proof enough, that it will not be executed dynamically when the code runs. I would be careful as hell to claim that the class is not used so we are safe, without understanding the technical context of what the class does and how it is used in the framework. If you don't want to go though the details this deep, do it differently. Unpack the jar, remove the class, pack the jar, see if it works.

Comment: I see ur point, but when reading the link issue I sent, can you tell whether the class is used by the framework itself and it is vulnerable or the class should be called by the app using the framework? I couldn't really understand it well as the java deserialization issue is new topic for me.

Comment: and for hwat you suggested, I'm not sure that is possible in a big application, even if I remove the class, I should try every single feature on the app because I don't know where apache commons is used.